# How to patch Python class using Mock library

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, scrapy, python-mock

I'm having trouble patching a class for my testing. I'm trying to patch something that belongs to Scrapy - a [HtmlXpathSelector](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html?highlight=HtmlXPath#scrapy.selector.HtmlXPathSelector) class.

Here is some code:

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from mock import MagicMock, patch

with patch('scrapy.selector.HtmlXPathSelector') as MockHtml:
    instance = MockHtml.return_value
    instance.method.return_value = 'foo'
    example = HtmlXPathSelector()
    print type(example)
    assert example is instance
    assert example.method == 'foo'
```

The result is:

```
<class 'scrapy.selector.lxmlsel.HtmlXPathSelector'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
AssertionError
>>>
```

This example is nigh on the same as the one in the Mock library tutorial. Any idea why it's not working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not patch a class already imported in the current test code. Instead you need to patch the class in the corresponding module (you want to test). So if `HtmlXPathSelector` is imported in `mymodule`, you will patch as:

```
with patch('mymodule.HtmlXPathSelector') as MockClass:
    ...
```

See [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) for further details.

**Edit** If you really need this, you can patch a class in the current module with:

```
with patch('__main__.Class') as MockClass:
```

Comment: Ahhh! This is what I want... I get it now, and this approach answers my comment in Ned's answer. Thanks!

Comment: Link where-to-patch at the momemnt is returning 503.

Comment: @Drachenfels Thanks, changed the link to point to readthedocs, should be more stable.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your code sample.  The first is that you've imported HtmlXPathSelector from the scrapy module, then you change that name after the fact.  Import selector instead, and use the name from there:

```
from scrapy import selector
from mock import MagicMock, patch

with patch('scrapy.selector.HtmlXPathSelector') as MockHtml:
    instance = MockHtml.return_value
    instance.method.return_value = 'foo'
    example = selector.HtmlXPathSelector()
    print type(example)
    assert example is instance
    assert example.method() == 'foo'
```

The other problem is that your last line was checking `method`, when it needs to invoke the method as `method()`.

Comment: This is great, thanks! The only issue is, the example I gave in my question is slightly simplified... The reality is that in the module I'm testing, `mypackage.foo_module`, `HtmlXPathSelector` is imported like this: `from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector`, and then the function I'm testing has an instantiation such as `hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(XX)`. Do I have to change the code in the class I'm testing to get it all to work then?

Comment: Either change your product code to import the way this sample does, or use `patch('mypackage.foo_module.HtmlXPathSelector')`.  This second way is probably better since it's a more localized change.

Comment: I get it now, Ned, Thanks. Rather serendipitously I was listening to your talk here http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/pycon-2010-tests-and-testability-188-3280697 just. And then you answered my testing question. How strange. :-)